# Jquery Chosen option hiding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen for multiple selection, when i chose an option and i click on add button that option am hiding and updating the chosen , but still that option is visible.

Below is the code.

```
$("#ddlcodes").find("option[value ='" + codeValue + "']").hide();
$("#ddlcodes").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Like above whenever i select and add , those options am hiding.
But only few options are hidden, few options are visible.

Below is DOM Html

```
<select id="ddlcodes" class="form-control code-change" style="display: none;"><option value="488" style="display: none;">33210</option>
<option value="489" style="display: none;">33213</option>
<option value="487">33208</option>
<option value="492">33284</option>
<option value="486">33207</option>
<option value="490">33216</option>
<option value="496">75724</option>
```

Hidden values not appearing in the drop down list. Refer below screen shot. Here 33210 appears for choosing.

[image]

[image]

Those options has to be removed from every where. how to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: plz accept an answer, so it can help other users

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $("#ddlcodes").trigger("liszt:updated");
```